# Laravel: how to get count() of all relations NOT collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have an accessor like so

```
  public function getRegisteredCountAttribute()
  {
    return $this->attendees->count();

  }
```

However, I have noticed that this counts the attendees in my collection after the query. So if my query removes some of the attendees I don't get the proper count.

Here is my query

```
        $programs = ScheduledProgram::where('registration_start_date', '<=', $today)
                                    ->where('end_date',                '>=',  $today)
/*                ->with(['attendees'=>function($q) use ($user_id)
                                        {
                                        $q->where('user_id', $user_id);
                                        }])
                                    ->with(['scheduledProgramSegments.attendees'=>function($q) use ($user_id)
                                        {
                                        $q->where('user_id', $user_id);
                                        }])
*/
                                    ->get();
```

I get a different number from my accessor `$program->registered_count` when I uncomment the comment in query section above. I guess that the accessor is giving me the count from the collection and not doing a new query to get the count I really need.

How do I get the count of registered attendees in the program?

I should note that the models `attendees`and `programs` have a many-to-many (`belongsToMany`) relation with a pivot table that also has fields for `registered, waitlisted`.

I saw [this article](http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-hasmany-relation-count-efficiently/) but I couldn't find the `next belongsToMany`.

**Models**

```
class ScheduledProgram extends Eloquent { 
 public function scheduledProgramSegments()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('ScheduledProgramSegment');
  }
  public function attendees()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Attendee', 'prog_bookings')->withPivot('registered','paid','waitlisted');
  }
  public function getRegisteredCountAttribute()
  {
    return $this->attendees()->count();
  }
}

class ScheduledProgramSegments extends Eloquent {
  public function attendees()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Attendee', 'bookings')->withPivot('paid');
  }
  public function scheduledProgram()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('ScheduledProgram');
  }
}

class ProgBooking extends Eloquent {
 public function scheduled_program()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('ScheduledProgram');
  }
  public function attendee()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Attendee');
  }
}
```

Comment: I found that ` return $this->attendees()->count();` works. But it increases the queries on my page from 13 to 146 and 14ms to 29ms :(

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch the **$programs** and eagerly load **attendees** with some additional constraint, those fetched filtered attendees are saved in **$program->attendees** attribute. When you call **count()** on that collection you'll get a number of attendees in that filtered collection.

If you need to count all attendees in given program you'll need to do:

```
public function getRegisteredCountAttribute()
{
  return $this->attendees()->count();
}
```

Notice the additional **()** - as a result you'll call **count()** not on the eagerly loaded collection of attendees with additional constraints applied - you'll call that on the relation itself.

Comment: Thanks, I just discovered that, see my comment to my original question. I was hoping to eager load it so that my queries don't increase by 1000% and  take 3 times as long...however, i will mark this correct in a day or 2 if nobody offers a better solution.

Comment: Which queries are you comparing?

Comment: I have a large dynamic list displaying records so the change with the additional `()` causes queries to be run for each record.

Comment: Then maybe the code needs to be refactored so that you run different queries? I can't help much without seing the code, but with what you describe if  you run it for every rown I can see why it's getting slower and it's definitely not a way to go. There are different options, like eagerly loading without constraints and then running count() with constraints applied which should give much better results. There might be some other better solutions on which I'm not able to elaborate withoug seing the code.

Comment: I do not understand how to run count() with contraints applied. You can see in my post I have a query with constraints commented out. Which is the first part of what you suggested. How do I do the other part?

Comment: I'll post an example in a moment. Could you show how you have defined relations ScheduledProgram->Attendee, ScheduledProgram->ScheduledProgramSegment and ScheduledProgramSegment->Attendee?

Comment: I have updated the question to show the models that are relevant so you can see how I defined the relation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83880/discussion-between-jedrzej-kurylo-and-phil).